# Entity Framework 5 Scaffold - EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, scaffolding

I am using Entity Framework 5.x.x to `Scaffold-DbContext` an existing SQL Server hosted database.

The database contains about 300 tables.

I would like the scaffolding to generate separate Fluent API `EntityTypeConfiguration` for each table/type instead of creating a `DbContext.OnModelCreating()` method with all the configurations in it.

The following article show how FLUENT API can be used to configure a EF Model.
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api

I want the `Scaffold-DbContext` tool to generate my configuration in the way it is shown here.

How to configure the scaffold tool to generate the configurations this way?

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can do this for you

Comment: Second ErikEJ's note - he's the author of EFCPT, but as a regular, unaffiliated user I'd also vouch for the considerable utility the extension represents. I don't have many things plugged into my VS, but that's on my mandatory list

Comment: Sadly EF Core Power Tools doesn't generate the EntityTypeConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

There are still no way to do this neither in EF core nor EF classic - [GitHub issue for EF Core](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8434).

You can look through the issue for some suggestions, for instance [this tool](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8434#issuecomment-564471303) for parsing large `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can!

Comment: I don't want to downvote, but I did want to ask you if you could qualify this answer a little better; the first sentence is sort of OK because it implies (though would be better if it stated clearly) *you can't do this with Scaffold-DbContext out of the box*... But the second sentence "The only option is" is far too definite, and not actually true..